# Ivy repository for maven projects

Tags: maven-2, pom.xml, dependency-management, ivy

We have an Ivy repository in place and we would like to develop new projects as maven projects but use Ivy for dependency management. Is it possible for maven to download artifacts from Ivy ? The articles I see are quite old, around 2011. Hence would like to check in the community once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is no.

The longer answer is that there is no standard ivy repository layout format. Maven on the other hand is more opinionated and really requires a repository manager. There are several recommended solutions: Nexus, Artifactory and Archiva. So install one of them. Upload the artifacts in your ivy repository and then let both your ivy and Maven builds share the same repo.